# Xerces no library found after install

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, xerces

I'm trying to run Xerces on Mac. I us

```
 ./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64" 
./configure --prefix=/opt
        sudo make (this builds the library)
        sudo make install (this installs the library)
```

I also include the `libxerces-c.dylib` on linker in NetBeans

Here is the error

```
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/xerces
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/_ext/619588065
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/_ext/619588065/SAXCount.o.d"
g++    -c -g -I/opt/lib/libxerces-c.dylib -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/_ext/619588065/SAXCount.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/_ext/619588065/SAXCount.o ../../Documents/xerces-c-3.1.2/samples/src/SAXCount/SAXCount.cpp
In file included from ../../Documents/xerces-c-3.1.2/samples/src/SAXCount/SAXCount.cpp:26:
../../Documents/xerces-c-3.1.2/samples/src/SAXCount/SAXCount.hpp:26:10: fatal error: 'xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp' file not found
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/_ext/619588065/SAXCount.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 128ms)
```

Any idea how to fix this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select Project in projects window.
2. Right-click for pop-up menu.
3. Select `Properties` in pop-up menu.
4. Select `C++ Compiler` under `Build` in Categories list on the left side of dialog.
5. Add a directory to `Include Directories`. The new directory should have  PlatformUtils.hpp in the `xercesc/util/` subdirectory of that directory. From your options I am guessing `/opt/include/`

**Update**

To Resolve

> ld: library not found for -lxerces-c

6. Select `Linker` under `Build` in Categories list on the left side of dialog.
7. Add the directory containing `libxerces-c.dylib` and/or `libxerces-c.a` which appears to be `/opt/lib/` to `Additional Library Directories` field.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I did that but still got the same error

Comment: What directory contains the file `PlatformUtils.hpp`?  What -I flags are being passed to the compiler? BTW  `-I/opt/lib/libxerces-c.dylib` doesn't make sense you should put include directories with .h and .hpp files on the include path with -I not .dylib files.

Comment: The directory that contain PlatformUtils.hpp is `/opt/lib/libxerces-c.dylib` I don't see say .h or .hpp file in `/lib` Here are the list of the file `libxerces-c-3.1.dylib` `libxerces-c.a` `libxerces-c.dylib` `libxerces-c.la`

Comment: This statement: The directory that contain PlatformUtils.hpp is /opt/lib/libxerces-c.dylib seems to directly contradict the statement that the list of files in that directory does not include PlatformUtils.hpp.

Comment: Hi, I did that, now that the 
`#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.`
Went away, some of the error still exist. Please see the link below [link](http://pastebin.com/t0J3hg9j)

Comment: and screenshot of my project properties [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=x5p5hk&s=9#.Vj0-iYTHfkw)  [link](http://i67.tinypic.com/x5p5hk.jpg)

Comment: Please see more image [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/rt0sip.png) [link](http://i64.tinypic.com/2zp1h1i.png)